# getting undefined on fetching rss feed

Tags: react-native, fetch, rss

I want to *randomly* display some of the news from a `google rss news feed` using the `url` and the package `react-native-url-preview`. Im doing a fetch call on it:

```
const [rssFeed, setRssFeed] = useState([]);
const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(true);
var feed = [];

if (shouldFetch) {
 console.log("shouldFetch");
 getFeed();
 setShouldFetch(false);
}

function getFeed() {
 console.log("getFeed: " + shouldFetch);
 fetch(
   "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=cars&hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen"
 )
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((responseData) => rssParser.parse(responseData))
  .then((rss) => {
    console.log(typeof rss.items);
    let feedItems = rss.items;
    feed = feedItems;
    // @ts-ignore
    setRssFeed(rss.items);
  });
}

if (!shouldFetch) {
 console.log(rssFeed);
 var randomArr = [];
 while (randomArr.length < 4) {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  if (randomArr.indexOf(r) === -1) randomArr.push(r);
  // @ts-ignore
  console.log(r + " " + rssFeed[r].links[0].url);
}
```

}

This only works sometimes!

50% of the times I get the error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'rssFeed[r].links'`.

I thought this is beacause of the reloading in `react-native` and this is why i put the `if` check. But it has not solved it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use optional chaining like `rss?.items`.

which means if `rss` is present check for `rss.item`.

```
rssFeed?.[r]?.links
```

Sometimes you get an Undefined Error because the UI gets rendered before the actual data is present.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It works, thanks mate! One thing to note though: the first time im loading the app, there is no news loading. Im working on it, but maybe you got any ideas?

Comment: Okay, got it. Solution: I used this check `rssFeed[0]?.links[0]?.url ? ` before rendering and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use "u" for "you". We're not texting, we're writing an article of solutions to a problem where grammar and spelling are important. Also, please format your entry for readability.